# Change tabs only in current group/pane

Tags: sublimetext2

I am working on a big display with high resolution, thus I work in multiple groups/panes as it is more productive (imho). I switch tabs using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> and groups/panes using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>9</kbd>. I want to 'lock' the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to current group/pane so it would not select tabs in another panes.

I really want that functionality but can't think of a way to achieve this. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple plugin to do it.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class ChangeViewCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, reverse=False):
        window = self.window
        group, view_index = window.get_view_index(window.active_view())
        if view_index >= 0:
            views = window.views_in_group(group)
            if reverse:
                if view_index == 0:
                    view_index = len(views)

            if reverse:
                new_index = view_index - 1
            else:
                new_index = (view_index + 1) % len(views)

            window.focus_view(views[new_index])
```

Then add the following to your user key bindings.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+tab"], "command": "change_view" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+tab"], "command": "change_view", "args": { "reverse": true } }
```

For focus group, there are already commands to go to groups 1 - 4, but you can add the following to go further (simply change the key binding number and group number)

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+1"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 0 } }
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much and I'm sorry for taking so long, somehow SO didn't notify me of the answer. I've edited your keybinding part by adding the reverse argument keybind :)